# What happens when two instances share the same elastic ip address?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Lets say I've got a domain pointed to an elastic ip with a record. If I've got two instances set to that elastic ip address, which one will you be directed to when you go to the domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "reassociation", and according to the [Elastic IP documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html)...

In EC2-Classic:

> If you try to associate an EIP that's already associated with another instance, the address is automatically associated with the new instance.

In VPC:

> If you try to associate an EIP that's already associated with another instance, it succeeds only if you allowed reassociation.

So in either environment the address won't stay associated with both instances.

Comment: I see. So basically it disassociates with the old and associates with the new? And AWS will only allow an elastic ip to be associated with 1 instance? I suppose if load balancing is setup, the elastic ip would need to be associated with the load balancer? P.S. I'm new to the cloud.

Comment: That's correct.  As far as load balancers go, it would be preferable to use the generated DNS name, or a friendlier domain name with the ELB instead: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-domain-names-with-elb.html